# What is the fallback font in ubuntu?

Tags: fonts

What font does Ubuntu use for really irregular characters like , and just general Chinese characters? Since it sort of falls back to a font that does have the glyphs, its impossible to tell where it's coming from. Also, does anyone know of any tools I can use to see what glyphs a *.ttf file supplies (For linux, naturally :P)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fallback fonts are decided by Fontconfig; it consults the configuration in `/etc/fonts` as well as the glyphs provided by all fonts to determine or decide which particular font is used to provide the character. You can right-click on a character in Character Map to see which font has been used to backfill the character.

Newer versions of GNOME Character Map can restrict display of glyphs to a specific installed font, but you will have to use something like FontForge in order to view available glyphs in a compact format.

Comment: A tip too: installing a font by dragging it into `~/.fonts` won't make the system use it. You have to add it info `fonts.conf`

Comment: Using the Gnome character map, you can also set it to view whatever default font you have where you are looking at (say, Ubunto Mono), then search for the replaced character in question, and right click on it. That will show the name of the fallback font for it.

Comment: @phipsgabler THANK YOU, this saved me hours of work.

Comment: The Character Map right click trick is exactly what I needed! The lack of discoverability for this feature is incredibly frustrating—especially because it's essential for web design.